# Ansible use different hostname if first fails

Tags: ansible, hosts

I have a number of raspberry pis that I swap out (only one running at a time) and run ansible against. Most pis respond to `ping raspberrypi` but I have one that responds to `ping raspberrypi.local`

Rather than remembering to manually ping the correct hostname before executing the playbook, is there a way in ansible to run a playbook against a different hostname if the first fails?

Currently my playbook is

```
---
- hosts: raspberrypi
```

and `/etc/ansible/hosts`

```
[raspberrypi]
raspberrypi
#raspberrypi.local
```

If I uncomment out the second hostname and the first fails, then the playbook will fail and not run on the `.local` hostname

Comment: FWIW: Fix the setup of your raspberries instead of trying to hack a workaround in Ansible ;-) ... And as a heads-up: Try to avoid name-clashes between Groups and Hosts - this can lead to playbooks not running on the systems you might expevt

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is directly possible in ansible.

But a hack I can think of is to create a list of hosts store them in a variable do a ping using the localhost. If ping is successful create a custom hosts group and execute the task you want to do.

Also are you executing your playbook with serial: 1 ?

Hope so this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the play against both host groups.

```
- hosts: raspberrypi:raspberrypi.local
```